# how to declare and use array 2 dimension

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I want to make like this:

```
uint8_t **t;
int i;
int m[100];
int i;
t = calloc(n, sizeof(uint8*));
...
/* m is initialized in other function */
...
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    /* m[i] is calculated here */        
    *t = calloc(1, sizeof(uint8)*m[i]);
}
```

I want to convert this behavior

```
byte [][]t;
int i;
int[] m = new int [100];
...
/* m is initialized in other function */
...
t = new byte[n];
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    /* m[i] is calculated here */
    t[i] = new byte[m[i]]; 
}
```

is it correct to do that

Comment: how to do the samething like C source code but using C#?

Comment: `t = new byte[n][];`?

Comment: either use new byte[n][] or use an actual 2d array byte[,] t = new byte[n, m]

Comment: the first does not work, the second I can't use it because m is not fix

Comment: See the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might a List work for you? Then you can just build an array of bytes as needed and add to the overall List collection object?

```
    List<byte[]> myByteList = new List<byte[]>();
    for (whatever loop )
    {
       byte[] justOne = however you build one byte array;

       myByteList.Add( justOne );
    }
```

Then you can iterate through it later....

```
foreach( byte[] oneByteArray in myByteList )
{
   do something with the oneByteArray;
}
```